# Non-administrator account in Vista cannot register ActiveX plug-in (won't let me install .dll)

Tags: dll, activex, windows-vista

So I wrote an ActiveX control but I can't install it anywhere when you are not administrator. Does anyone know a work-around for this (that doesn't involve an administrator)?

Comment: That's the point of having a machine administrator: to not let anybody install stuff. If there's a work-around, then it's a security flaw waiting to be exploited (if not already).

Comment: ...but only if this workaround includes the installation of the COM component. SxS may come to rescue here... the component is only "virtually" registered and not installed in the system, but the application can still use it normally.

Comment: Hmm I will check out this SxS. Might be the most promising thing for me.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one - you have to be an administration to do a lot of installation bits and pieces, and registering an ActiveX control is one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by using [registration-free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) - with [Side-by-Side assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376307(VS.85).aspx) (SxS).

Comment: It doesn't seem to support vista: "Registration-free COM is a mechanism available on the Microsoft Windows XP (SP2 for .NET-based components) and Microsoft Windows Server 2003 platforms."

Comment: That's because this article is quite old (2005) and has not been updates. Google for Vista SxS and you'll see that it is also available.

Answer (score 0):

Since Internet Explorer 8 there are [Non-Admin ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433049%28VS.85%29.aspx) in Vista, it does not require user’s admin privileges. All you need is to modify .inf file:

```
//From MSDN: 

[Deployment]
    InstallScope=user

[contoso.dll]
    file-win32-x86=thiscab
    clsid={ABC01234-BA7A-101A-B57A-0000C0C3EFF0}
    FileVersion=4,20,0,6164
    RegisterServer=yes
    RedirectToHKCU=yes
```

Also, Active Directory allows [ActiveX installation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280579) for User Group members, but I’m not sure this is your case…

Otherwise, the user must have admin rights.